# Shell_NotifyIconA / Shell_NotifyIconW...whats the difference?

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, interop, pinvoke

I am porting some Win32 code to C#, and have come accross several functions which have the same names and use the same structures except that they end with A and W

For example:

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
[DllImport("shell32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern bool Shell_NotifyIconA(uint dwMessage, ref NOTIFYICONDATAA lpData);

[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
[DllImport("shell32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern bool Shell_NotifyIconW(uint dwMessage, ref NOTIFYICONDATAW lpData);
```

I have seen some implementations in C# which omit the A and W from both the function name, and the associated structure, like so:

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
[DllImport("shell32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern bool Shell_NotifyIcon(uint dwMessage, ref NOTIFYICONDATA lpData);
```

What I want to know is:

1. What do A and W denote?
2. In C#, should I implement the functions as shown above, using both A and W, or is it better practice to omit A and W in favour of having a single implementation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "A" suffix (which stands for ANSI) means that the function works with input *multi-byte strings* (probably some members of `NOTIFYICONDATA` are strings), while "W" (which stands for "Wide") means the function works with input Unicode strings.

In Windows, it is better to work with Unicode strings whenever possible, because that's what the OS *internally* uses. Thus, if your project invokes a Windows API by passing a multi-byte string, a conversion to Unicode will eventually happen internally (and possibly a second conversion back to multi-byte if the OS also *returns* you a string), slowing things down.

Usually, when two versions of a certain data structure of function `X` exist for multi-byte and Unicode characters, they are given the names (respectively) `XA` and `XW`, and a conditional alias `X` is defined to resolve into one or the other based on your project's settings (an `#ifdef` does the switch).

I do not know enough about C# to answer the second part of the question.

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by [David Heffernan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan), the p/invoke marshaller will resolve the name to the one that matches the `CharSet` used in the `DllImport` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. My gut feeling is that C#'s interoperability layer will do, as you say, take X and resolve it to XA or XW automatically depending on the runtime platform. +1 for answer!

Comment: @Tolga, I usually wait a while to see if there are any more answers before marking it as a solution. If there are no other answers within a few hours, then I will mark this as a solution.

Comment: The p/invoke marshaller will choose a name suffix that matches the CharSet.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, what if no CharSet property is specified?

Comment: There is a default CharSet, which is ANSI