# Show windows balloon notification on table insert

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows

I am developing a windows application using C# . I want to show a balloon notification when a new row is inserted into a specific table. The application will be installed on many computers and will share a common database through LAN. Currently I am achieving this using polling. That is the application will query the database table each second to check if a new row is inserted.Please let me know whether this is the correct method or is there a better method for this? I know that using trigger we can execute queries in SQL server for table inserts, but is it possible to send a message back to the particular application from SQL server that has inserted the new row into the table? Please help

Comment: Very open question... There are lots of approaches! Do you have a central service or do all the clients hit the database on each request?

Comment: polling a database every second is likely bad for performance. Personally I would look into having a windows/web service that handles notifications and relays them out to all connected application. So when one instance of your app inserts a row, it notifies the service and then the service send out a notification to all the other connected (listening) applications. Good luck!

Comment: @Belogix       Thanks. I don't have a central service. All the clients will poll the database. Please let me know the best approach. How can I create a central service?

Comment: @musefan        Thanks. Please let me know how can I create a windows service that handles notifications.

Comment: @user1690835: Sorry but it is too much for me to be able to guide you through. You need to go a research the concept and see what you can implement on your own. Perhaps look into WCF, [here is a good start](http://idunno.org/archive/2008/05/29/wcf-callbacks-a-beginners-guide.aspx).. like I said, good luck, it's not easy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can accomplish this with a combination of a SQL CLR Trigger and a Win32 API Function. Using the CLR Trigger will help avoid polling.

[Here's an MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/938d9dz2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) on writing the CLR Trigger.

The sample code shown is logging to some audit table. Swap that part to make a call to the Shell_NotifyIcon Win32 API function. 
[Here's a sample from MSDN on using the **Shell_NotifyIcon**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940367(v=vs.85).aspx)  to display the balloon notification.

The actual sample code is [on this page](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/shellintegration) (search for notificationicon.zip) and written in C++, but you should be able to modify it for C# once you do the DLL Import and use PInvoke. See [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14673155/325521) for more on that.

Comment: Do I understand this correctly: this CLR trigger would notify **any** instance of the application of an insert? Or would it notify only the instance that initiated the insert?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but I think it will notify only the instance that initiated the insert. To broadcast it, I wonder if you can raise an event in the CLR function that clients can subscribe to and in that event, do the Balloon notification.

Comment: Then perhaps you should expand your answer. The OP is using polling, which most probably means they want to detect *any* new inserts to the table.

Comment: We are talking 3 different needs here. 1 is to detect new INSERTS. 2 Broadcast those inserts to ALL Clients. 3 Use Taskbar Ballon notification to broadcast individual messages. OP is using Polling to detect INSERTS, not to broadcast the messages. The CLR Trigger will solve #1, and the Win32 API code will solve #3. I'm leaving it up to OP to implement #2.

Comment: They are polling the table to detect an insert. They use that method so that *any* instance of the application can see *any* insert. And they are looking for an alternative to the polling method. If you meant to answer the question, I would expect your suggestion to be that alternative, but you yourself said to the effect that it might not be so. That's why I am suggesting that you expand your *answer* with whatever additional information necessary to make your approach an actual replacement for the OP's implementation. (I realise, though, that it already may be a good starting point as it is)